# how to identify whether mingw compiled library with success

Tags: makefile, compilation, mingw, vmime

i'm tackling the problem of compiling vmime library using [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20151201200805/http://vmime.omgwtfbbq.nl/) guide with MinGW. As this guide states, first i need to compile libiconv library with these commands(yep i'm new to MinGW):

$ tar -xvvzf libiconv-1.13.1.tar.gz

$ cd ./libiconv-1.13.1

$ ./configure --prefix=/mingw #configures makefile, use /mingw as a prefix

$ make

$ make install

after all this commands the libiconv.dll.a appears in libiconv-1.13.1\lib.libs 
directory.Also after compiling process appears the /bin directory and there is only 1 library - libcharset-1.dll.

My question is - how do i know if the library properly compiled, without errors?Should i check the output from the MSYS console? there are tons of checks, it seems pretty boring task. Thanks in advance, glad to hear any advice!

Comment: If there were errors it wouldn't have compiled.

Answer (score 0):

You're building a [GNU Autotools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Build_System) package.

`./configure` generates the makefile(s) needed by `make` to build the library
on your particular system. If it thinks the library can't be built on your particular
system, it will tell you why. It might just miss some reason why you can't build
the library, because the library developer(s) have to script the tests that it runs, and might
just overlook some necessary ones. But if it misses something then `make` will fail.

`make` executes all the commands necessary to build the library on your system. If any of them fail,
then `make` will fail, and will tell you so unmistakably.

Likewise `make install` does everything necessary to install the library
under the default or specified `prefix` path.

Classically, unix tools (like the autootols) will inform you when something goes wrong
and not inform you that nothing went wrong.